# Установка библиотеки boost в QtCreator

Tags: boost, qt

Доброй ночи, уважаемые коллеги!

У меня возникла следующая проблема. Мне надо установить в Qt creatore библиотеку boost. Я скачал библиотеку, установил ее в папке `D:\boost_1_54_0`. (Я пытаюсь сделать как сказано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113679/configure-qt-creator-to-use-boost-on-windows)) Далее в теле программы в проекте `.pro`  я пишу следующие вещи.

```
TEMPLATE = app 
CONFIG += console    
CONFIG -= app_bundle    
CONFIG -= qt    
SOURCES += main.cpp    
win32 {   
    INCLUDEPATH += D:/boost_1_54_0       
    LIBS += -LC:/boost/lib \       
            -lboost_serialization-mgw46-mt-d-1_54 \       
            -lboost_filesystem-mgw46-mt-d-1_54 \      
            -lboost_system-mgw46-mt-d-1_54      
}
```

Когда же я пытаюсь скомпилировать код программы, мне выдается ошибка

```
cannot find -lboost_filesystem-mgw46-mt-d-1_54

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Либо,если это можно, скиньте, пожалуйста, инструкцию, как устанавливать boost на Qt.

**Обновление**

Вот смотрите, я правильно понял, что надо было в строке

```
INCLUDEPATH +=
```

написать, где находится папка `boost_1_54_0`? Я ее скопировал в `D`. При этом сам `QtSDK` находится на `С`. Мне надо скинуть всю папку `boost_1_54_0` в какое то определенное место? Я просто, честно говоря, не совсем еще понимаю,что нужно прописывать в либах. Я пытаюсь прописать `LD:/boost_1_54_0\lib`, однако проблема не решается. Нужно ли какой-нибудь дополнительный дистрибутив ставить?

Comment: А у Вас случайно после символов `\` нет пробелов? Там их не должно быть.

Comment: Вадим, я проверил, пробелов не оказалось.

Comment: А пути точно правильные прописаны? а то меня немного смущает, что include находятся на D, а либы на С.

Comment: буст это интересная библиотека и ее нужно компилировать отдельно. и некоторые люди считают, что ее нужно компилировать только самостоятельно. Но это для ценителей. Для обучения можно просто поискать скомпилированный буст. В нем как раз и будут lib и dll файлы, которых Вам не хватает.

В каталоге `D:/boost_1_54_0\lib` или какой Вы там себе пропишете, должны быть файлы с расширением lib или a.

Answer (score 3):

`-L"PATH"`  говорит что указывается папка где линковищик будет искать lib файлы. Проверьте что в папке `C:/boost/lib` которую вы указали лежит скомпиленая либа `boost_filesystem-mgw46-mt-d-1_54.lib`

Вот пример указания где у меня лежит . Лень перекладывать было указал как есть.

```
-L"C:\usr\lib\boost_1_57_0\bin.v2\libs\system\build\msvc-12.0\debug\architecture-ia64\link-static\threading-multi"
 -llibboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_57
```

P.S. Если вы просто распаковали сорцы, то и либы не будет. Надо все это дело собирать. Читайте доки как собрать в папке буста.